# Writing dictionaries by Arrays into a csv file and inserting new lines by Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, csv, data-structures

I am trying to insert a new line into a csv file that I am writing this data into. The data is

```
data = [[{'Hi': 'O'}, {'mr': 'O'}, {'you': 'O'}, {'president': 'O'}, {'USA': 'Country'}, {'for': 'O'}, {'answering': 'O'}, {'football': 'O'}, {'questions': 'O'}, {'music': 'JAZZ'}], [{'Hi': 'O'}, {'You': 'O'}, {'have': 'O'}, {'granted': 'STATE'}, {'purchased': 'O'}, {'GHC3': 'O'}, {'Bundle': 'O'} {'248803151': 'O'}]]
```

This is the code I have but I am not sure how to re-code it to accommodate the new line per array in the data.

```
def convert_to_biolu(dico, biolu_list = defaultdict(list)): #dico here is output_data
  for dict_item in dico: # you can list as many input dicts as you want
      for key, value in dict_item.items():
        if value not in biolu_list[key]:
          biolu_list[key].append(value)
  return biolu_list

def save_to_file(path, data_):
    data_ = [convert_to_biolu(item) for item in data][-1]
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        fieldnames = ['word', 'label']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for key, val in data_.items():
          writer.writerow({'word': key, 'label': " ".join(val)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write csvs without the module.

I prefer to do it myself like this:

```
def write_csv_with_spaces(data, filename):
    with open(FILENAME, 'w+') as file:
        for list in data:
            for dict in list:
                file.write(','.join([str(key) + ',' + str(value) for key,value in dict.items()]) + '\n')
            file.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this breaks each character to a new line instead of a new word. It does not attach the label as well.

Comment: Oh yeah, try it now.